# UITextField "Next" Adding Extra Newline to UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a `UITextField` and a `UITextView`. When I hit "Next" (The return button on the keyboard) on the `UITextField`, I want to switch first responder status to the `UITextView`. My code is successful in switching the first responder, but also adds an extra newline to the beginning of the `UITextview`, which I would like to avoid.

The only code I have is as follows:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: return `NO` instead of `YES`.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy! I searched around. Don't know how I missed that other question